# Help me calculate with maple the gcd of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, maple, gcd-and-lcm

I can't calculate the gcd of two polynomials $x^2 + (\beta^3 +1)x + \beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta$ and $(\beta^5 + \beta^3 + 1)x + \beta^5 + \beta^3 + \beta^2$ where beta is the root of $x^6 + x + 1$, beta belong Field[2],$F_{2}[x]$ , and all polynomials belong $F_{64}[x]$. Help me please.
I am using maple 12, but I can't calculate it myself or by using maple.

Comment: Sorry about grammer, i don't know English well. Thanks for editting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm amazed that no one has yet answered this easy Question---easy if you know Maple, that is.

```
restart:
alias(beta = RootOf(y^6+y+1)):
Gcd(
     x^2+(beta^3+1)*x+beta^4+beta^3+beta^2+beta,
     (beta^5+beta^3+1)*x + beta^5+beta^3+beta^2
) mod 2;
```

Maple's response is 1, so the polynomials are relatively prime.

Comment: I so sorry , my answer was lacked. All polynomials belong to F[64]. My code is same with you. I also tried evala(Gcd....) but the result was not correct, in my book, the result is $x + \beta + 1$

Comment: Then either the book is wrong, or you entered the problem wrong in your Question. I've rechecked the computations by hand, and the answer is 1. Also do **Gcdex(p,q,x,'s','t')** where **p** is the first polynomial and **q** the second. Then expand **s\*p+t\*q**. You will get 1 after you reduce it.

Comment: thanks for your help, i am so ashame,  exactly, i wrote wrong quetion in my notebook. Exactly "beta^5+beta^2+1", so sorry for wasting your time. In other time, i can ask you a problem again ?

Comment: If you post any Question here and tag it "maple", I'll see it. Also consider posting Maple Questions to mapleprimes.com. Also, I think that you should either vote my Answer or select it as the best Answer, or both.

Comment: did i vote and select answer, ? this is first time i have answered this page. Thanks for help !

Comment: You can calculate it by hand. Can you share me doccument about it, i can't calculate it if not use maple.

Comment: My computations are too rough and shorthand for someone else to decipher. But, anyway, do you want to see the computation for the original pair of polynomials or the corrected pair? In either case, the simplest first step is to factor the leading coefficient from the second polynomial. Can you compute the quotient of two elements of F[64]?

Comment: Sorry you. I don't understand clearly your question , thus i can't answer . thanks you for your help in maple.